# Mapped Drive not working from GPO

Tags: active-directory, gpo, mapped-drive

I am trying to map a network drive within an Active Directory Group Policy Object.

When the domain was setup, we had a consultant map the first drive for us and it is working fine.

I am going back to map a second drive to a targeted group (e.g. security group).  I have modified the mapped drive settings that the consultant setup to add a 2 and 3 level mapped drive location.  Rebooted client computer...did a gpupdate /force...nothing shows up.

I then create a new GPO and added to the root of my users OU (same place where the consultant had the other GPO that is working) and put in the mapped drive settings.  Did a gpupdate /force and a reboot, but still nothing.

Trying to figure out if I missed something.  Or if there is a way to verify the client is receiving the mapped drive settings.

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks
jlimited

Comment: Server:  Windows Server 2012 R2  Client: Windows 7 Pro

Comment: How are you mapping the drive?  Group Policy Preferences, Group Policy, Script?  On the client machine, logged in as the user, open a cmd and type 'Gpresult /r > gpout.txt'.  Copy to contents of gpout.txt here.  What's the name of the Group Policy that you created that is mapping the drive?

Comment: Here is the content of the gpout.txt.  Thanks for showing me that...it was helpful.

Comment: OS Configuration:            Member Workstation
OS Version:                  6.1.7601
Site Name:                   OnPrem
Local Profile:               C:\Users\tgassmann

COMPUTER SETTINGS
    CN=JM-0001,CN=Computers,DC=CORP,DC=JMMS,DC=US
    Last time Group Policy was applied: 4/24/2016 at 6:48:40 PM
    Group Policy was applied from:      PRDDC02.CORP.JMMS.US
    Domain Name:                        JMMS
    Domain Type:                        Windows 2000

    Applied Group Policy Objects
        Default Domain Policy
        Local Group Policy

Comment: The computer is a part of the following security groups
    -------------------------------------------------------
        BUILTIN\Administrators
        Everyone
        SQLServerMSSQLServerADHelperUser$JM-0001
        BUILTIN\Users
        NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK
        NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users
        This Organization
        JM-0001$
        Domain Computers
        Authentication authority asserted identity
        System Mandatory Level

Comment: USER SETTINGS
    CN=Travis Gassmann,OU=Technology Services,OU=JMMS Users,DC=CORP,DC=JMMS,DC=US
    Last time Group Policy was applied: 4/24/2016 at 6:30:34 PM
    Group Policy was applied from:      PRDDC02.CORP.JMMS.US
    Domain Name:                        JMMS
    
    Applied Group Policy Objects
        Map drives and printers
        Map T Drive (Repository)

Comment: The following GPOs were not applied because they were filtered out
        Default Domain Policy
            Filtering:  Not Applied (Empty)
        Local Group Policy
            Filtering:  Not Applied (Empty)
        WSUS JMMS-COMPS
            Filtering:  Disabled (GPO)

    The user is a part of the following security groups
        Domain Users
        NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users
        JMMS VPN
        Database DBO
        Domain Admins
        Technology

Comment: From the output I see the "Map T Drive (Repository)" Applied Group Policy Objects.  which is the policy that I want to work.

Comment: But the T Drive is not mapping.  I am using the Group Policy Management Editor > User Configuration > Preferences > Windows Settings > Drive Maps.  Position 1 is delete T:\.  Position 2 is create T:\ mapping to \\<server>\<fileshare>

Comment: I have also tried the Update Drive Map function as it creates it, if it does not exist.  Neither of these are working.

Comment: But the default GPO "Map drives and printers" is working correctly.

Comment: A quick point on etiquette; use PasteBin and link outputs, or edit your original question and add more information.  The mods might not like you posting multiple comments.

Comment: So the GP is applying, that's now out of the equation.  The computer is failing to map the drive. 

Firstly delete one of the positions on the GPO, make it 'create' to simplify the situation.

Some other prereq's. Logged in as the user:
- can you navigation to \\<server>\<fileshare>?
- can you map \\<server>\<fileshare> to T: manually (disconnect it after)?
- the T: drive isn't already in use is it?

After the above, if stil not working, restart the machine, log in and go straight to the system event log, follow the logs from the time of reboot, for relevant info, pay attention to red dots.